# [Gitlab CE]Cann't see master branch on website.Looks like the master didn't point any commit.How do I fix it?

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, gitlab-ce

I have a self host gitlab ce service.

I can't see master branch of my respitory on website.

Try this after I found the problem:

1. Push my local branch **master**  to origin/master

```
(master)# git push -u origon/master
error: src refspec refs/heads/master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'origon/master'
```

`git fetch` is not working either. 
2. create a new **master** branch on website . Not working

So I go checking the repository on gitlab server.Seems the master exist. But did not point to any commit.

```
root@Gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/lianjc/Intelligent_Entrance_Guard.git# cat refs/heads/
for_origin_db  m2             master         
root@Gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/lianjc/Intelligent_Entrance_Guard.git# cat refs/heads/
for_origin_db  m2             master         
root@Gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/lianjc/Intelligent_Entrance_Guard.git# cat refs/heads/m
m2      master  
root@Gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/lianjc/Intelligent_Entrance_Guard.git# cat refs/heads/master 
root@Gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/lianjc/Intelligent_Entrance_Guard.git# cat refs/heads/m2     
852a5dfd5849ccb81def6f0ef223dbed87ff7f6e
root@Gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/lianjc/Intelligent_Entrance_Guard.git# cat refs/heads/for_origin_db 
852a5dfd5849ccb81def6f0ef223dbed87ff7f6e
```

Can I just edit the file "refs/heads/master ", make it pointing to a commit ?
Or anything I can do on the website?

Sorry for my poor english.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA7dM.png)Can't post images.

Comment: "*Push my local master branch to origin [rejected]*" What was the error? Please [edit].

Comment: @phd thank for you advice. Already edit. Please check it again and help